# java Swing using JFrame.pack() repeatedly - how efficient is it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In short I was wondering, if I call `JFrame.pack()` on a frame that is already sized, will it take a long time to analyse this or will it simply return immediately?  I ask for efficiency reasons.  There is a picture in my frame that is being updated many times a second within a loop.  Now `JFrame.pack()` has to be called after at least the first picture is drawn to insure that the frame is the right size.

To handle this what I have (in pseudo code) is:

```
boolean flag = false
while (condition) {
    getNextPicture();
    updateFrameWithPicture()
    if (!flag) {
        frame.pack()
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Now I was wondering if there would be a problem if I just left out the check for the flag and always called `frame.pack()`.  Could the program decide fast enough if the frame is already the correct size?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. Then you can report your results back here. Although I doubt you should be using a while loop as you may block the Event Dispatch Thread and prevent it from updating the GUI. Normally you would use a Swing Timer to schedule updates. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. The tutorial also contains a section on `How to Use Timers`.

Comment: @camickr  Tricky to estimate differences in performance as I am displaying images received on an RTP socket.  I am actually using a swing timer - just thought it would be easier to describe my question in terms of a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tricky to estimate differences in performance as I am displaying images received on an RTP socket.

You are micro optimizing your code. Getting external data through a socket will always be slower than repainting a frame.

> I am actually using a swing timer

You should NOT use the Timer to do the actual reading of the image on the socket. The GUI will block while the image is being read. You should be using a separate Thread to read the image. It will probably be better for you to use a `SwingWorker` and then `publish()` the images as they become available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

> just thought it would be easier to describe my question in terms of a while loop.

No, it is better to give the actual code as you can see your current code is incorrect. Don't make use guess what you are doing.